# Trying to understand the security aspect of custom npm package which will be shipped with a ReactNative Mobile application

Tags: react-native, npm, package

I've created one custom npm package which is calling post api, and data of post api we are taking from parent react-native mobile app.

For api call I've used axios package.

So now I need help for 2 scenarios:

1. How I can private my package to app specific?

- I want to allow only my organization to use this package. For other apps I want to restrict package installation.

2. How I can secure my api call from any vulnerabilities?

- I want to secure my api call which I am calling through axios package, can you suggest me what process I need to follow to secure api call inside custom package?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've edited my description, please go through that once. Let me know if you want more description @Community